# Having trouble with being selective in list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I need to use a list comprehension to convert certain items in a list from Celsius to Fahrenheit. I have a list of temperatures. What my best guess is at this point looks like this:

```
good_temps = [c_to_f(temp) for temp in temperatures if 9 < temperatures[temp] <32.6]
```

However I'm not doing something right and I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution to the one pointed in another answer is to use filter to get the subset:

```
filter(lambda temp: 9 < temp < 32.6, temperatures)
```

Then a list comprehension to make the transformations:

```
[c_to_f(temp) for temp in temperatures]
```

Final expression:

```
good_temps = [c_to_f(temp) for temp in filter(lambda t: 9 < t < 32.6, temperatures)]
```

Comment: it seem this will mix in converted and uncoverted temps into `good_temps`

Comment: @tenwest, you're right, I was confused by his "certain items in a list" part, but it doesn't make any sense to convert selectively (in this context).

Comment: ah yes I glazed over that part, now I better understand the downvote hah

Comment: I appreciate that you don't want people to think you're copying my code, but `filter` is overkill here. It makes the code more complicated to read, and slower.

Comment: @PM2Ring, absolutely, and this is not only about the performance, it is not pythonic, since there is better (natural) way pointed out in your answer. I just don't want to just copy that here :)

Comment: I keep seeing lambdas on here, but so far I haven't come across them in my lessons, does anyone have a good tutorial for them or is the Python documentation pretty clear on it?

Comment: @user3650751: There's a little bit of info on lambdas in [the reference section](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda) of the docs, and a bit more in [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions). Lambdas are pretty simple: they're just a convenient way to write a one-line function. You can't do assignments in the body of a lambda, all you can do is return the value of an expression.

Answer (score 2):

You're very close. What you need is:

```
good_temps = [c_to_f(temp) for temp in temperatures if 9 < temp < 32.6]
```

This code will only convert `temp` if it's greater than 9 and less than 32.6. For `temp` values outside that range nothing will get added to `good_temps`.

`temp` is already an item from `temperatures`, so `temperatures[temp]` doesn't make much sense, since that's attempting to use an item of `temperatures` as an index.

Comment: I'm stuck at work, but I can't tell you how excited I am to get back to it! Thank you very much. I'm happy that I was close. I kept getting a syntax error on the < and it was throwing me off

Comment: I don't. What is this? I've been getting by with windows Powershell doing everything in Python.

Comment: @user3650751 repl.it gives you a way to play with Python (& other languages) when you have Net access but you don't have Python installed on that device. There are various other online Python interpreters, but repl.it is one of the more popular ones. Another big favorite is [PythonAnywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com); which offers all sorts of interesting services.